# Como guardar en el Escritorio en otra ruta?

Tags: java, itext

Hola estoy usando esta linea de código y lo estoy mandando al desktop:

```
String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Reporte Alumnos.pdf"));
```

pero mi escritorio es otro y esta en datos E: como puedo mandarlo ahi
en java

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente define la ruta en la cual se creará el archivo, en este caso en el drive E:, por ejemplo:

```
String ruta = "E:\datos";
PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "\Desktop\Reporte Alumnos.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de diferentes formas:

- Definiendo la ruta de forma manual:

```
String ruta = "E:" + File.separator + "datos";
PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Reporte Alumnos.pdf");
```

- Obteniendo la ruta del home del usuario:

```
String rutaEscritorio = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop";
PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(rutaEscritorio + File.separator + "Reporte Alumnos.pdf");
```

La forma correcta sería la segunda, ya que obtiene la ruta independientemente del usuario que lo este ejecutando. En ambos casos puedes añadirle el directorio Desktop en el String o después como parámetro.